# Freeglut cause "ERROR: Function called without first calling 'glutInit'." while using glut methods inside library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform, glut, freeglut

I will start from my project struct. I'm **statically** linking freeglut to **shared** library where I have keyboard callback:

```
// DECLARATION
TW_API int twKeyCallbackGLUT_d (unsigned char key, int mouseX, int mouseY);

// DEFINITION
int TwEventKeyboardGLUT(unsigned char glutKey, int mouseX, int mouseY)
{
    int kmod = 0;
    int glutMod = glutGetModifiers();

    if( glutMod&GLUT_ACTIVE_SHIFT )
        kmod |= TW_KMOD_SHIFT;
    if( glutMod&GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL )
        kmod |= TW_KMOD_CTRL;
    if( glutMod&GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT )
        kmod |= TW_KMOD_ALT;

    if( (kmod&TW_KMOD_CTRL) && (glutKey>0 && glutKey<27) )  // CTRL special case
        glutKey += 'a'-1;

    return TwKeyPressed((int)glutKey, kmod);
}

TW_API int twKeyCallbackGLUT_d(unsigned char key, int mouseX, int mouseY) {
    return TwEventKeyboardGLUT(key, mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

Then, i'm linking that library to my executable, where i'm using following code:

```
void onKeyboardKey(unsigned char key, int mouseX, int mouseY)
{
    // send event to AntTweakBar
    if (twKeyCallbackGLUT_d(key, mouseX, mouseY))
        glutPostRedisplay(); // request redraw if event has been handled
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    // Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("AntTweakBar string example");
    glutCreateMenu(NULL);
    glutGetModifiers(); // test line

    // Set GLUT callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(OnDisplay);
    glutReshapeFunc(OnReshape);
    std::atexit(onTerminate);  // Called after glutMainLoop ends

    // Initialize AntTweakBar
    TwInit(TW_OPENGL, NULL);

    // Set events callbacks:
    glutMotionFunc(onMouseMotion);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(onMouseMotion);
    glutMouseFunc(onMouseButton);
    glutKeyboardFunc(onKeyboardKey);
    ...
}
```

The problem is when program hits glutGetModifiers() inside library callback I got "ERROR: Function  called without first calling 'glutInit'." and application exit due to https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/FG_3_0_0/src/fg_state.c#L298 but i'm calling glutInit properly inside of my main() as you see. `glutGetModifiers(); // test line`in main doesn't cause this error.

Be aware, application runs successful and all callbacks works perfectly (mouse callback for example), application fails when i'm pressing any keyboard key, because key callback the only one where i'm using glut method. I figured out that when I go inside library methods scope `fgState.Initialised` (variable of freeglut that true if glutInit was called) equal to 0, but while my executable scope that equal to 1.

Most weird thing come when I decided to check on other build system, since i'm using Cmake, I configured project for MinGW and got successful build, glutGetModifiers() calls fine with no error occur, only VS2015 cause it.

Last thing I checked was threads, I thought my library for some reason using another thread for callback (or VS creating other thread), but it's not, all application consist in a single thread.

Could someone explain to me, why this error appears on VS and not appears on MinGW build, it so confusing me~

**UPD1:** I've made minimal example of project that cause the issue https://gist.github.com/Liastre/97dc12c01da097406cbf5beecada474c

**UPD2:** Static linking of my library doesn't cause the issue (since in this case, freeglut should be linked directly to executable), so problem appears when freeglut not directly linked to executable.